# Custom HTML link is not working

Tags: theming

I have used a custom html link [More search results](/homepage)   to link to the homepage.
When clicking the link,I am taken to this url`http://localhost/homepage` instead of the correct one `localhost/cars/homepage`
What am I doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: this is the html link I created <a href="/homepage">More search results</a>

Comment: I don't understand the problem - If you want it to link to /homepage/cars, why are not using /homepage/cars as the href?

Comment: I want to link to localhost/cars/homepage and it sends me to localhost/homepage .It removes the "car" .My site is localhost/cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is installed in the /cars folder, but you're pointing to the root of the server by using the forward slash at the front of your HREF. You should use Drupal's `l()` function to generate a proper link:

`<?php echo l(t('Homepage'), 'homepage'); ?>`